# List and description of all packages in CRAN from within R

Tags: r

I can get a list of all the available packages with the function:

```
ap <- available.packages()
```

But how can I also get a description of these packages from within R, so I can have a `data.frame` with two columns: package and description?

Comment: I seem to remember this being asked before.  What searches have you tried?

Comment: Some similar things were asked before (eg: classification by name length, adding date of package)  and I have also looked at the available package() function to see if there was an optional parameter for description but I have not yet managed to find a solution for this.

Comment: The solution would involve adding the parameter `fields="Description"` or perhaps better `fields="Title"`, but it doesn't seem to return anything from the CRAN mirror I use with `available.packages`. It works with `installed.packages` though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Edit* of an almost ten-year old accepted answer.  What you likely want is *not* to scrape (unless you want to practice scraping) but use an existing interface: `tools::CRAN_package_db()`.  Example:

```
> db <- tools::CRAN_package_db()[, c("Package", "Description")]
> dim(db)
[1] 18978     2
>
```

The function brings (currently) 66 columns back of which the of interest here are a part.

---

I actually think you want "Package" and "Title" as the "Description" can run to several lines.  So here is the former, just put "Description" in the final subset if you *really* want "Description":

```
R> ## from http://developer.r-project.org/CRAN/Scripts/depends.R and adapted
R>
R> require("tools")
R>
R> getPackagesWithTitle <- function() {
+     contrib.url(getOption("repos")["CRAN"], "source") 
+     description <- sprintf("%s/web/packages/packages.rds", 
+                            getOption("repos")["CRAN"])
+     con <- if(substring(description, 1L, 7L) == "file://") {
+         file(description, "rb")
+     } else {
+         url(description, "rb")
+     }
+     on.exit(close(con))
+     db <- readRDS(gzcon(con))
+     rownames(db) <- NULL
+
+     db[, c("Package", "Title")]
+ }
R>
R>
R> head(getPackagesWithTitle())               # I shortened one Title here...
     Package              Title
[1,] "abc"                "Tools for Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC)"
[2,] "abcdeFBA"           "ABCDE_FBA: A-Biologist-Can-Do-Everything of Flux ..."
[3,] "abd"                "The Analysis of Biological Data"
[4,] "abind"              "Combine multi-dimensional arrays"
[5,] "abn"                "Data Modelling with Additive Bayesian Networks"
[6,] "AcceptanceSampling" "Creation and evaluation of Acceptance Sampling Plans"
R>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this suffers from the same *column-by-column* display issue, when trying to print or view the entire df. I described this in my own answer post.

Answer (score 7):

Dirk has provided an answer that is terrific and after finishing my solution and then seeing his I debated for some time posting my solution for fear of looking silly.  But I decided to post it anyway for two reasons:

1. it is informative to beginning scrapers like myself
2. it took me a while to do and so why not :)

I approached this thinking I'd need to do some web scraping and choose crantastic as the site to scrape from.  First I'll provide the code and then two scraping resources that have been very helpful to me as I learn:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

URL <- "http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_summary.html#summary_by_package"
packs <- na.omit(XML::readHTMLTable(doc = URL, which = 2, header = T, 
    strip.white = T, as.is = FALSE, sep = ",", na.strings = c("999", 
        "NA", " "))[, 1])
Trim <- function(x) {
    gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
}
packs <- unique(Trim(packs))
u1 <- "http://crantastic.org/packages/"
len.samps <- 10 #for demo purpose; use:
#len.samps <- length(packs) # for all of them
URL2 <- paste0(u1, packs[seq_len(len.samps)]) 
scraper <- function(urls){ #function to grab description
    doc   <- htmlTreeParse(urls, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
    nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//p")[[3]]
    return(nodes)
}
info <- sapply(seq_along(URL2), function(i) try(scraper(URL2[i]), TRUE))
info2 <- sapply(info, function(x) { #replace errors with NA
        if(class(x)[1] != "XMLInternalElementNode"){
            NA
        } else {
            Trim(gsub("\\s+", " ", xmlValue(x)))
        }
    }
)
pack_n_desc <- data.frame(package=packs[seq_len(len.samps)], 
    description=info2) #make a dataframe of it all
```

**Resources:**

1. [talkstats.com thread on web scraping (great beginner
   examples)](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/26153-Still-trying-to-learn-to-scrape)
2. [w3schools.com site on html stuff (very
   helpful)](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_nodes.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to try to do this using a HTML scraper ([rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html)) as an exercise, since the `available.packages()` in OP doesn't contain the package *Descriptions*.

```r
library('rvest')
url <- 'https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html'
webpage <- read_html(url)
data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'tr td')
length(data_html)

P1 <- html_nodes(webpage,'td:nth-child(1)') %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)  # XML: The Package Name
P2 <- html_nodes(webpage,'td:nth-child(2)') %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)  # XML: The Description
P1 <- P1[lengths(P1) > 0 & P1 != ""]  # Remove NULL and empty ("") items
length(P1); length(P2);

mdf <- data.frame(P1, P2, row.names=NULL)
colnames(mdf) <- c("PackageName", "Description")

# This is the problem! It lists large sets column-by-column,
# instead of row-by-row. Try with the full list to see what happens.
print(mdf, right=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)

# PackageName Description                                                             
# A3          Accurate, Adaptable, and Accessible Error Metrics for Predictive\nModels
# abbyyR      Access to Abbyy Optical Character Recognition (OCR) API                 
# abc         Tools for Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC)                        
# abc.data    Data Only: Tools for Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC)             
# ABC.RAP     Array Based CpG Region Analysis Pipeline                                
# ABCanalysis Computed ABC Analysis

# For small sets we can use either:
# mdf[1:6,] #or# head(mdf, 6)
```

However, although working quite well for small array/dataframe list (subset), I ran into a display problem with the full list, where the data would be shown either *column-by-column* or unaligned. I would have been great to have this *paged* and properly formatted in a new window somehow. I tried using *page*, but I couldn't get it to work very well.

---

**EDIT:**
The recommended method is not the above, but rather using Dirk's suggestion (from the comments below):

```r
db <- tools::CRAN_package_db()
colnames(db)
mdf <- data.frame(db[,1], db[,52])
colnames(mdf) <- c("Package", "Description")
print(mdf, right=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

However, this still suffers from the display problem mentioned...

Comment: It's 2018, and things got easier. Try to start from what `db <- tools::CRAN_package_db()` returns -- N rows with 65 columns where N is the current number of CRAN packages.  You should be able to work with that more easily than by scraping.