# How to list a large dataframe row-by-row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

While trying to answer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227315/1147688) SO question, I came across a curious problem with a *large* dataframe (DF). I wanted to print the DF ***row-by-row***, but for some reason it insists in printing the DF in a *column-by-column* fashion and I am not able to find a way to print the whole thing in a nice way, to get the formatting I would like to see (and preferably be able to scroll through), without considerable performance loss.

The following behave differently, depending on the *length* of the DF columns. When small it looks great and works as expected, but when large, 
it prints *column-by-column* (or doesn't align when using different methods). The R-package DF is **13022** rows long.

```r
# Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227315/1147688
print(mdf, right=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)

# PackageName Description                                                             
# A3          Accurate, Adaptable, and Accessible Error Metrics for Predictive\nModels
# abbyyR      Access to Abbyy Optical Character Recognition (OCR) API                 
# abc         Tools for Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC)                        
# abc.data    Data Only: Tools for Approximate Bayesian Computation (ABC)             
# ABC.RAP     Array Based CpG Region Analysis Pipeline                                
# ABCanalysis Computed ABC Analysis
```

---

Q: **Any ideas how to do this *natively* without having to resort to looping over indexes?**

PS. I am already aware of the related suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642535/creating-an-r-dataframe-row-by-row).